# Find a basis for this subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

$ S = \{ (x,y,z,t) \ \in \ \Bbb{R}^4 ; x =0, y = \frac{-t}{2} , z = \frac{t}{2} , t \ | \ t \ \in  \ \Bbb{R}  \}. $

My attempt:

$ x (0,0,0,0) + t (0, - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},1). \\$
$$
\displaylines{
c_1  \begin{bmatrix} 
        0\\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0  
     \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} 
        0\\
        - \frac{1}{2} \\
        \frac{1}{2} \\
        1  
     \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 
        0\\
        0\\
        0 \\
        0  
     \end{bmatrix}
}
$$

$\{(0,0,0,0),(0, - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},1)\}$ or only $(0, - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},1)\}$ is basis for this subspace? I am confused for find solution

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The zero vector can't be an element of a basis since it is not linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard

Comment: There's one independent parameter ($t$) which determines the points in the subspace so it will have dimension $1$.

Comment: @Berci If I understand correctly, the basis is $(0, - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},1)$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Berci thank you